# Closing Opened Program Via PHP

Tags: php, windows, apache

Im trying to find a way to close a program that i have recently opened with PHP. Part of a start and stop server system ( Server made in java with .bat ). I can only get it to open in the background, and yes i have the interact with desktop enabled. I was wondering if there was a way i could return the PID of the proccess of program i initiate at first, then use that pid to close the program at a later time.

PHP PAGE CODE FOR STARTING

```html
<?php 
        session_start();
        $id = $_GET['serverid'];

                $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mainrspshosts");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE id = '" .$id. "' LIMIT 1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($_SESSION["username"]==$row["owner"]){


set_time_limit(300);


    echo "Starting...<br><br>";
$output = shell_exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START run474.bat');
    echo($output);
    echo "Success!";
        header("refresh:5;url=http://rspshost.zapto.org/ucp/serverstartedvalidation.php");











        }
        else{

        header("location:index.php");
        
        }
    }
}
else{

        header("location:index.php");
}



        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't need to open cmd.exe individually, shell_exec means running a command on console as you are probably passing a command to run cmd via this

```
 c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /
```

so you can just write it as

```
 shell_exec("start /filepath/fileName.bat");
```

As far as your question is concerned, php shell_exec just executes the command passed to it, it doesn't know the meaning of the command. Since the closing mechanism of each application, that you run via shell_exec would be different, so you need to close it via shell_exec by passing another command that stops or kills the process. In your case, create a

```
 closing-run474.bat file
```

and call it via shell_exec

Comment: The problem is the program stays running until i need to close it via the script again. So im not sure how i would even go about making a bat file to close it.

Comment: Thats the thing, i dont know what command to use! I was going to use the PID to do it, but i dont have a way of recording the pid for each process. (Its going to be started multiple times )

Comment: I seriously doubt doing this in PHP. As @DanyalSandeelo mentioned, use a script that actually is able to record anything executed on the shell. You can save stuff to a file, e.g. the PID of the executed process to kill the process later.

Comment: in linux, we have have ps -ef | grep PROCESS , I grep java processes like ps -ef | grep java.. that shows me the java processes..what kind of service is that? there must be some way to close it..see if you can find that way..You might need to ask another question that would be like asking how to close that particular service via command line..